# Swift - Can I use realm in Notification Service Extension?

Tags: swift, database, notifications, realm, unnotificationserviceextension

As the title, can I use realm in Notification Service Extension ?

When I receive a notification, I need to get some data from realm, then edit notification content before showing to user.

I do below in the Podfile

```
pod 'RealmSwift'

target 'NotificationServiceExtension' do

  inherit! :search_paths

end
```

Then I import RealmSwift in NotificationService.swift .

But it seems not working because it doesn't use the same database and can not find the scope I've already created.

Comment: Super helpful tutorial [here](https://agostini.tech/2017/08/13/sharing-data-between-applications-and-extensions-using-app-groups/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works, you need to create an `AppGroup` in order to share data between your app & the Extension.